# Permission management in aspboilerplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I am currently working on **multitenant saas webapp** using *aspboilerplate* and would like to implement the **permission management** but I got little bit of confusion.

Firstly, what's the difference between `MultitenancySides.Host` and `MultitenancySides.Tenant` which I have found [here](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/eventcloud/blob/master/aspnet-core-angular/aspnet-core/src/EventCloud.Core/Authorization/EventCloudAuthorizationProvider.cs)....

```
 public override void SetPermissions(IPermissionDefinitionContext context) 
    { 
       context.CreatePermission(PermissionNames.Pages_Users, L("Users")); 
        context.CreatePermission(PermissionNames.Pages_Roles, L("Roles")); 
        context.CreatePermission(PermissionNames.Pages_Tenants, L("Tenants"), multiTenancySides: MultiTenancySides.Host); 
        context.CreatePermission(PermissionNames.Pages_Events, L("Events"), multiTenancySides: MultiTenancySides.Tenant); 
    }
```

Secondly, how `[AbpAuthorize]` differs to

```
[AbpAuthorize(PermissionNames.Pages_Tenants)]
```

I found those in event service ( [first link](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/sample-odata/blob/master/AbpODataDemo-Core/aspnet-core/src/AbpODataDemo.Application/MultiTenancy/TenantAppService.cs)  and [second link](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/eventcloud/blob/master/aspnet-core-angular/aspnet-core/src/EventCloud.Application/MultiTenancy/TenantAppService.cs))  ,

```
[AbpAuthorize] 
    public class EventAppService : EventCloudAppServiceBase, IEventAppService 
     { 
        private readonly IEventManager _eventManager; 
         private readonly IRepository<Event, Guid> _eventRepository;
```

and in TenantService

```
 [AbpAuthorize(PermissionNames.Pages_Tenants)] 
    public class TenantAppService : AsyncCrudAppService<Tenant, TenantDto, int, PagedResultRequestDto, CreateTenantDto, TenantDto>, ITenantAppService 
     { 
        private readonly TenantManager _tenantManager;
```

Here is what I want and expect to implement permissions in my Multitenant Saas **(Core + Angualr SPA)** ...
There will be different features ( I say modules) including Event (`CRUD`), Library(`CRUD`), Exam(`CRUD`), Result(`CRUD`), Attendance(`CRUD`) and I would like to have full access (`CRUD`) permission to tenant superadmin (by default assigned when tenant is created) and then superadmin can create role (Assigned module and permission (`CRUD`) to specific module).

To make it simple, if system has Attendance module/feature then by default a tenant's `Superadmin` will have full `CRUD` access whereas if `Staff` role is created and restricted to `CR` but not allowed to `UD`.

I have gone through [this](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Articles/Developing-MultiTenant-SaaS-ASP.NET-CORE-Angular/index.html) tutorial but unable to sort it out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Firstly, what's the difference between `MultiTenancySides.Host` and `MultitenancySides.Tenant`?

`MultiTenancySides.Host` → can only be assigned to Host users (`user.TenantId == null`).

`MultiTenancySides.Tenant` → can only be assigned to Tenant users (`user.TenantId != null`).

> Secondly, how `[AbpAuthorize]` differs from `[AbpAuthorize(PermissionNames.Pages_Tenants)]`?

`[AbpAuthorize]` → user is logged in.

`[AbpAuthorize(PermissionNames.Pages_Tenants)]` → user is logged in and has that permission.